# Ridge regression not appropriate for collinearity caused by mathematical constraints on the data

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, ridge-regression, regression-strategies

In this paper:

Use of the Bootstrap and Cross-Validation in Ridge Regression
Author(s): Nancy Jo Delaney and Sangit Chatterjee Source: Journal of Business & Economic Statistics, Vol. 4, No. 2 (Apr., 1986), pp. 255-262

The authors state that:

> "As a caveat to the implementation of the ridge model, it must be pointed out that the cement data represent a mixture problem. The four independent variables add to approximately 100 for each observation. The ordinary ridge model is not appropriate for collinearity caused by physical or mathematical constraints on the data. Unfortunately, the ridge technique is often illustrated by this data set."

What I'm concerned about is whether this criticism is valid in my situation?

I'm using the [Nelson-Siegel-Svensson model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson-Siegel#Modeling_the_yield_curve).

So I have a set of observations (which theoretically at least) are generated by the 4 factor model shown in the link above. In the extreme case that $\tau_1 =\tau_2$ then the factors relating to B2 and B3 will be perfectly collinear. (Obviously I would not envisage such a situation I am more interested in when these values are close). But for the purposes of this question suppose that they are: in that case it seems like I have a situation as described by Chatterjee and Delaney does this mean that Ridge regression is not appropriate in this case? If not what methods should I be using?

Comment: why are you using a ridge regression in the first place?  and how are you choosing lambda?

Comment: The lambdas (and betas) are chosen via a genetic algorithm. If I let the algo run without any constraints it will pick collinear often highly collinear sets of lambdas. As these provide the best fit in the Least squares sense and there is nothing theoretically that I know of that would prevent the actual parameters from being collinear. So I am using ridge regression to try and get more accurate estimates of the betas for these multi-collinear lambda values.